# Is there a bug when bit-shifting on the avr-gcc compiler?

Tags: avr-gcc

while working with bit shifts on the atmega328 chip under avr-gcc 5.4.0 I noticed a bug(?). Let's see some snippets:

This code works as expected:

```
uint32_t val = 0xaabbccdd;
Serial.println( val, HEX ); //Output: aabbccdd
// For testing 32 bit variables
```

This one also works:

```
uint16_t read = 0x3FF;
uint32_t val = read * 65536;
Serial.println( val, HEX ); // Output: 3ff0000
```

But this is not!:

```
uint16_t read = 0x3FF;
uint32_t val = read << 16;
Serial.println( val, HEX ); // Output: 0
```

(With values less than 16 the system even crashes!)

Is there any known bug in the compiler?

Comment: `uint32_t val = (uint32_t) read << 16;`

Comment: I thought every bit in 'read' that was left shifted enters into 'val', but it seems the shifting is done completely in 'read' before its new value is copied to 'val'.

Comment: The same "bug" was biting me for the past two days and I just discovered it! I was bit-shifting the 16-bit timer1 to covert counts to microseconds and adding it to the uint64_t system time - all in one line of code. And I could not figure out while my time intervals were off. This is so crazy! Your code compiled for AVR results in overflow and yields 0. However, compiled for PC, it results in 0x3ff0000. That is a big discrepancy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   uint16_t read = 0x3FF;
   uint32_t val = read << 16;
```

Since `read` is only 16 bit wide and 16 zeroes are shifted in from the right, the result in `val` is `0`. You have to use a explicit cast to uint32_t as already suggested in the comments.

```
   uint16_t read = 0x3FF;
   uint32_t val = read * 65536;
```

This works without a cast, because 65536 is handled as an int32_t (because it does not fit into uint16_t) and thus, the result of the multiplication is int32_t and does not overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a bug. I found this page searching the Internet for "gcc bit shift bug".

I had the following lines in my code for AVR-GCC:

```
uint32_t startBit
///
startBit = (uint32_t)1 << (combinationLength-1);
///
uint32_t pm
///
pm = (uint32_t)1<<in;
///
uint32_t totalCombinations = (uint32_t)1 << totalInputs;
```

All times I had to add the cast explicitly due to erraical behavior of the code.
The first one was filling the higher bits with "1" giving false negative compare with zero.
I didn't analyzed the 2nd case, and the 3rd was generating zero by shifting the 1 to the bit 16 instead of 65536 and it seems that immediate values are by default 16 bit in AVR-GCC, or bit-shift is by default 16-bit.

Comment: It's not a bug. The C/C++ spec says that the result of a 16-bit shift is again a 16-bit value. And "1" is a 16-bit value on avr-gcc. Moreover, shift offsets that are the width of a type or more is Undefined Behaviour.